# why is ember instantiating multiple route classes

Tags: ember.js

It seems like ember is instantiating multiple route files, but I can't figure out where the documentation is that would have taught me this

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('admins', { path: '/admins/:admin_id' }, function () {
    this.route('foo');
    this.route('bar');
}
```

I then I have 4 files

```
routes/admins.js
routes/admins/index.js
routes/admins/foo.js
routes/admins/bar.js
```

If I go to `/admins/12` there are 2 routes that are getting instantiated:  the one from 
`routes/admins.js` and `routes/admins/index.js`

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

index is a free route under a resource that is automatically hit when you hit that resource.  You don't have to define the template/route.

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Personally it's a convenient route when you want something to be displayed when you just hit the root of a resource, but then don't want it displayed when you hit another route/deeper resource/routes.